# The terminal will switch to the first tab when the window is active. How to disable that?

Tags: terminal

If I open several tabs in the terminal, minimize the window and make the window active again, the first tab will be switched on. I want to keep my last chosen tab on when I active the terminal, which I believe is the expected behavior before. Is there any setting I missed to fix that?

I recorded a video to show my issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNT1D.jpg

System: macOS 10.13.2.

Comment: There's no setting for that.  I tested in El Cap and Sierra and the behavior is as expected.  It may be a bug in HS.  Additionally, I would give [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) a try.

Comment: FWIW, I was able to duplicate your bug in HS Terminal. Not a problem in iTerm2 tho.